# Replace dot with comma, and comma with dot PHP

Tags: php, type-conversion, number-formatting, price, money-format

i have a price column in a table. price is Turkish lira like that. 1.200,50.
i want to make +%10 to price. but give me  1.32 not 1.320,55

here is my code

```
<?php
$num = "1.200,50";
$newnum=$num*10/100+$num;
$formattedNum = number_format($newnum, 2);
echo $formattedNum;
?>
```